# how to change site path and create subdomain using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, redirect

i have a site with the index.php located at the server public root.

the url is

```
 http://example.com
```

i have created a subfolder called 'travel' and moved the whole site content into it.

Using .htaccess , how can i have my site now at this adress ( with the subdomain travel):

```
http://travel.example.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Why htaccess and why not just VirtualHost entry in Apache config like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com 
    DocumentRoot /www/domain
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName travel.example.com
    DocumentRoot /www/domain/travel
</VirtualHost>
```

**EDIT .htaccess based solution:**

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^travel\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (?!travel/)^(.*)$ travel/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: the site is hosted in a paas and i am afraid i can't access to the server conf.

Comment: Where is `travel.example.com` pointed to at present to? Does it open same `index.php` from server public root?